# Null output in scrapy after entering data in form

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrape a webpage which has a form and once entered, it fetches data in the same page.
The link to the page does not change after the button is clicked.

I am trying to scrape the data once the form is filled and here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser



class EmailSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'email'
    allowed_domains = ['phpans.com/free-email-validator']
    start_urls = ['http://phpans.com/free-email-validator/']

    def parse(self, response):

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                formdata={'email':'ndiveshjain@gmail.com','validate':'true'},
                                                callback=self.after_enter,
                                                dont_filter = True,
                                                )
    def after_enter(self,response):

        chec = response.xpath('//*[@id="message"]').extract_first()
        yield{'Name':chec}
```

The link to the website is: https://phpans.com/free-email-validator/

The after_enter function runs that means I think that the form is successfully submitted but then the output which I want does not appear.

Can anyone help me understand what is the mistake here in my code?

Any help would be appreciated and I don't want to use selenium. So, if anyone can help me scrape this page, it would be really helpful.


Also, I have made ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

So, robots.txt should not be the issue.

This is the output which I receive and there is no error and no output, please see where I have gone wrong.

```
    (base) C:\Users\Divesh\email_validator>scrapy crawl email
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: email_validator)
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'email_validator', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'email_validator.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['email_validator.spiders']}
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 2b5415ce25525ddc
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-12-29 12:06:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-12-29 12:06:45 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://phpans.com/free-email-validator/> from <GET http://phpans.com/free-email-validator/>
2019-12-29 12:06:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://phpans.com/free-email-validator/> (referer: None)
2019-12-29 12:06:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://phpans.com/free-email-validator/> (referer: https://phpans.com/free-email-validator/)
2019-12-29 12:06:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://phpans.com/free-email-validator/>
{'Name': None}
2019-12-29 12:06:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-12-29 12:06:46 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 891,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5076,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.08303,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 29, 6, 36, 46, 777725),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 29, 6, 36, 44, 694695)}
2019-12-29 12:06:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As in the output, I am getting the name output as none which should be some value after entering data in the form and validating. Hence, I think some changes has to be made and if anyone can help me, it would be really great
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: When I uses form on this page then it shows nothing. What did you see on this page?. Besides this page uses JavaScript and Scrapy can't run JavaScript. you may needd Selenium to run JavaScript on this page.

Comment: Read about [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) would be helpful.